# A set of generators in disjoint cycle notation. Сompute the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algorithms, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I study the solvability in radicals of irreducible polynomial of degrees 5,6,7. For this I seek the Galois group of these polynomials. In Mapple, there is a halo function(https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=galois). One of the values (number 5) that it returns is (5 A set of generators in disjoint cycle notation.The generators are represented by strings) is what I need. Maybe someone knows whether there are analogs to this function (the most important thing is 5 point) in Java, C ++ Python or something else.
irreducible polynomial degrees 5,6,7

Comment: Galois group of which polynomials?

Comment: Galois group of an irreducible polynomial  degrees 5,6,7

Comment: It depends on the coefficients of the polynomial. For example look at the Galois group of [irreducible cubic polynomials](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf)

Comment: Polynomials like a1x^7+a2x^6+a3x^5+a4x^4+a5x^3+ a6x^2+a7x where 0 ⩽  a1 .... a7 ⩽ 10